# Prove that the area of the triangle with vertices $z, wz, z+wz$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}|z|^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, triangles

> Prove that the area of the triangle with vertices $z, wz, z+wz$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}|z|^2$

**My Attempt**
$$
A=\frac{i}{4}\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1\\
z&wz&z+wz\\
\bar{z}&\bar{w}\bar{z}&\bar{z}+\bar{w}\bar{z}\\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
=\frac{i}{4}\bigg[wz(\bar{z}+\bar{w}\bar{z})-\bar{w}\bar{z}(z+wz)-z(\bar{z}+\bar{w}\bar{z})+\bar{z}(z+wz)-z(\bar{w}\bar{z})-\bar{z}(wz)\bigg]\\
=\frac{i}{4}\bigg[ w|z|^2+|w|^2|z|^2-\bar{w}|z|^2-|w|^2|z|^2-|z|^2-\bar{w}|z|^2+|z|^2-{w}|z|^2-\bar{w}|z|^2+w|z|^2 \bigg]\\
=\frac{i|z|^2}{4}\bigg[ \color{red}w+\color{blue}{|w|^2}-\color{green}{\bar{w}}-\color{blue}{|w|^2}-\color{brown}1-\color{orange}{\bar{w}}+\color{brown}1-\color{red}{w}-\bar{w}+w \bigg]
=\frac{i|z|^2}{4}(w-\bar{w})
$$
How can it be same as $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}|z|^2$ ?

Comment: Something is missing, perhaps $\omega$ is complex cube root of unity.

Answer (score 1):

HINT...It is easier just to draw a picture. Assuming that you mean $\omega$ is a cube root of unity, the three points form an isosceles triangle whose two equal sides have length $|z|$, since $|\omega z|=|z|$, and the angle between these sides is $120^o$

The answer you obtained is equivalent to the answer given because $\omega=\cos120^o+i\sin120^o$